# Android Format calendar to output time

Tags: java, android

I am using the below code to set an alarm. I would like to output what the time for this would be. I don't know if I going about this the wrong way. If I output the variable cal it has a long string of information. How do I extract only the hour and minutes?

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // add 5 minutes to the calendar object
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 464);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) method on your `Calendar` object, and use `Calendar` static constants for the needed field (hour, minute, etc...).

For example:

```
cal.get(Calendar.Minute);
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use the static constants as m0skit0 says, or use `SimpleDateFormat`.  Here's some code to show both methods:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 464);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

outputs:

```
05:31
5:31
```

Comment: hiii i would like to set static time like this..
2013-07-11T12:00:00.000+05:30

here my date is not static.while i am select the date from calendar is 22 july 2013 then i want 2013-07-22T12:00:00.000+05:30 like this.how is it posible?

Comment: @Google you should ask a new question, rather than commenting on an existing answer