# Set Time in HH:MM format in Seek Range Bar

Tags: android, seekbar

[image: My Sample Range Outlook]

I want to display time in range bar like this. I want to its minimum and maximum value in time format like HH:mm style. I am getting output but not in perfect. I want to set my value from morning 6:00 AM to Night 11:59 PM.

Where I am making a mistake? I want my date in 15 minutes interval like 6:00--> 6:15--> 6:30-->6:45... and so on

What I did is here.

**Activity Class**

```
enter code   // Gets the RangeBar
    rangebar = (RangeBar) findViewById(R.id.rangebar1);
    rangebar.setTickCount(25 * SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);//SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION = 4;
    rangebar.setTickHeight(0);
    rangebar.setThumbRadius(8);
    rangebar.setConnectingLineWeight(3);



    // Sets the display values of the indices
    rangebar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(new RangeBar.OnRangeBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIndexChangeListener(RangeBar rangeBar, int leftThumbIndex, int rightThumbIndex) {
            DecimalFormat deciFormat= new DecimalFormat("00");

            leftIndexValue.setText("" + leftThumbIndex);
            rightIndexValue.setText("" + rightThumbIndex);

            int minHour = leftThumbIndex / SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION;
            int minMinute = SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION * (leftThumbIndex % SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);
            int maxHour = rightThumbIndex / SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION;
            int maxMinute = SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION * (rightThumbIndex % SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);
            leftIndexValue.setText(minHour + ":" + minMinute);
            rightIndexValue.setText(maxHour + ":" + maxMinute);

            leftIndexValue.setText(deciFormat.format(minHour) + ":" + deciFormat.format(minMinute));
            rightIndexValue.setText(deciFormat.format(maxHour) + ":" + deciFormat.format(maxMinute));
        }
    });
```

here

Comment: You have a OnSeekBarChangeListener?

Comment: Hi.. I am using this library https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar

Comment: And I have setOnRangeBarChangeListener

Answer (score 0):

set setNotifyWhileDragging option

```
 rangebar = (RangeBar) findViewById(R.id.rangebar1);
        rangebar.setTickCount(25 * SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);//SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION = 4;
        rangebar.setTickHeight(0);
        rangebar.setThumbRadius(8);
        rangebar.setConnectingLineWeight(3);
        rangebar.setNotifyWhileDragging(true);
```

And set onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged Listener

```
  rangebar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
          // set bar value And Text
        }
    });
```

Comment: But I am using rangeBar and I already put value 4. Please go through my code

Comment: set setNotifyWhileDragging And set onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged

Comment: it would be great help from your end :)

Comment: actually i need your help now. Surely I will vote you but please first give me solution

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake in calculating hours and minutes based on thumb indexes. There is a proper calculation:

```
hours = thumb / SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION; // SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION should be defined as int
minute = (thumb % SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION) * (60 / (float) SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);
```

And I believe that you should specify the max range as rangebar.setTickCount(24 * SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION); (there are 24 hours per day).

But there is a better way to format dates and times. Take a look at Calendar and SimpleDateFormat classes: [Android Format calendar to output time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463328/android-format-calendar-to-output-time)

Comment: Thank you Alexander. Surely I will test and will let you know